# How do I pass the data include the file in the type of form-data in postman by react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, form-data

First, I was new to react, I need to pass the data from frontend to backend by API. The data are in the type of form-data from POSTMAN. Below the picture show the API work in POSTMAN

[image]

I use form-data here for my API data.

So here the problem.
Since this is first time I am handle on this issue of passing file to form-data. Below code is what I am do:

```
 constructor (props){
        super(props);
        const supplier_id = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('id'));
        this.state ={
            supplier_id: supplier_id,
            item_name:'',
            item_shortDes: '',
            item_longDes: '',
            price: '',
            terms_agreement: '',
            Location: '',
            selectedFile: null,    // The item file which I need to pass to api.
          redirect: false,
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.createItem = this.createItem.bind(this);
      }

      createItem(){
        console.log(this.state)
        fetch(`http://localhost:9000/api/item/submit`, {  // callling the API here
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)   
        }).then ((result) => {  
                let responseJSON = result;
                console.log(responseJSON);
                });
      }
```

I get the error here:

[image]

So I believe this is  because of Im not passing through the type of `form-data`. am I right? How would I going to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

the first you need for send form data you have to call form data class like the blew.

`formData = new FormData()`

then start to append your form data

`formData.append("keyName",`${keyName}`)`